# How can I get more informative errors with Go json.Unmarshal?

Tags: json, go, serialization, json-deserialization

All the error from json.Unmarshal says is "cant Unmarshal {" or whatever character it's failing at. With a large enough JSON file, it can be very difficult to figure out where the malformation is.

I'd like to find a way to get a more specific location, using a combination of functions supported by the json library or others. One possibility can be the line and character number of the failure. I'd also be happy to get the tree path to the malformation.

Comment: you can use an editor to find a json tag error by saving the file as .json

Comment: You'll have to do that yourself. But with the JSON input, and the offset provided by the error, it should be an easy exercise to determine which line the error was on.

Comment: To add to Flimzy comment, you can get offset like this: `var offset int64; if synErr, ok := err.(*json.SyntaxError); ok { offset = synErr.Offset }`.  From there, it's up to you to convert to line, column or whatever else you want.

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked perfectly!